# How to Jasmine Spy on private member variables in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node module with a function constructor. I want to spy on a private property within that module but can't figure out how to spy on it. As soon as I create a closure around it I can't see it anymore from the test. The code...

```
//logger.js
function Logger(){
   this.log(str){...}
}

//mainMethod.js
var Logger = require('Logger');

function mainMethod(){
  var logger = new Logger();
  logger.log('error')
}

exports.mainMethod = mainMethod;

//my test
it('when main method is called then logger will log "error"',function(){

   spyOn( ... ?)

   expect(logger.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('error');

}}
```

Clearly the test does not work. So I don't really know how to spy on that logger. I can't use a singleton since each node request must use a new object. If this was C# I would simply use dependency injection and then spy on the interface. But everywhere I read that node does not need a DI container. Please can someone help?